# Does Catalina synch and backup devices running iOS 12?

Tags: ios, ipad, backup

I've got one of the first generation iPad Airs and it will only update to iOS 12.4.2.  I'm trying to back it up and synch it using my iMac on which I've installed Catalina (10.15). The iPad shows in the sidebar of Finder but when I click on it, after a minute of waiting I get a message saying "The selected device could not be found."  I have no problem backing up and synching my iPhone which is running 13.1.2 and I've had no problems backing up and synching this iPad in the past. Does anyone know if the new method works with devices running iOS 12?

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204095 <- If your computer doesn't recognize your iPhone, iPad, or iPod

Comment: @ankii My iPad shows in the list produced by this computer.  However the problem doesn't go away.  I still can't use Finder to backup or synch the device.  The same message still appears in the Finder window.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you try this:

https://www.catalinaosx.com/macos-catalina-continuity-issues-device-timed-out/

Comment: I'm not using Bluetooth or Wifi.  I'm connected directly with the charging cable.

Comment: What does it say ? [answer]: Provide context for links

Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: @ankii The message is quoted in the original post: "The selected device could not be found."  Unfortunately that's all it says.

Comment: @AlMaki it was meant for Udhy